# CSS - Add tangent rectangle onto top of concentric circles

Tags: html, css

I am trying to recreate this graphic but I am a bit stuck on how to add the tangent rectangle on top of the outer concentric circle and below the 3 sided rectangle object as shown below. Additionally, the height of the rectangle should be tall enough so that it only touches the outside of the inner circle. This is what I have so far on jsFiddle.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Kaevonz/mowahL2v/35/

[image]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.elem {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div1 {
  border-top: 3px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-left: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-right: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  height: 70px;
  width: 120px;
  background: white;
}

.div2 {
  border: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.div3 {
  border: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background: white;
}

.div4 {
  border-top: 0.5px dashed black;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.div5 {
  border: 0.5px dashed black;
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="elem div1"></div>
  <div class="elem div2">
    <div class="elem div3">
      <div class="elem div5">
        <div class="elem div4">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using a relative position for div2, so i would use a `position: absolute` on div5:

```
.div5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border: 0.5px dashed black;
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

The transform property, combined with the left property is to make sure that your element is centered.

Then, i would remove your div4 from div3, because it looks like you're creating relationships between divs that don't seem to be necessary (Unless there is a mathematical reason for that):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="elem div1"></div>
  <div class="elem div2">
    <div class="elem div3">
      <div class="elem div5">
      </div>
      <div class="elem div4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.elem {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div1 {
  border-top: 3px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-left: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-right: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  height: 70px;
  width: 120px;
  background: white;
}

.div2 {
  border: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.div3 {
  border: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background: white;
}

.div4 {
  border-top: 0.5px dashed black;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.div5 {
  border: 0.5px dashed black;
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
   <div class="elem div1"></div>
   <div class="elem div2">
     <div class="elem div3">
       <div class="elem div5">
       </div>
       <div class="elem div4">
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```